# Transformar resultado do banco em JSON no padrão do Amcharts

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou usando o framework Code Igniter.
Tenho o seguinte model:

```
public function getVendasVendedor() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM vendas_vendedor");

        return $query->result();    
}
```

Meu Controller:

```
public function retornaJsonVendasVendedor() {
    echo json_encode($this->vendasm->getVendasVendedor());
}
```

Retornando JSON do controller:

```
[{
    "anomes":"201601",
    "totven":"1218000.0000",
    "codven":"117285",
    "nomeven":"JOAO FELIPE RIBAS"
},
{
    "anomes":"201701",
    "totven":"78000.0000",
    "codven":"117285",
    "nomeven":"JOAO FELIPE RIBAS"
},
{
    "anomes":"201602",
    "totven":"2800.0000",
    "codven":"109959",
    "nomeven":"JIAN LEANDRO FERMINO"
}]
```

Debug do resultado do Model:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201601
        [totven] => 1218000.0000
        [codven] => 117285
        [nomeven] => JOAO FELIPE RIBAS
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201701
        [totven] => 78000.0000
        [codven] => 117285
        [nomeven] => JOAO FELIPE RIBAS
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201602
        [totven] => 2800.0000
        [codven] => 109959
        [nomeven] => JIAN LEANDRO FERMINO
    )
)
```

e preciso gerar um JSON, no seguinte padrao, que seria para um gráfico usando o amcharts:

```
[{
  "category": "2013-08-24",
  "value1": 417,
  "value2": 127
}, {
  "category": "2013-08-25",
  "value1": 417,
  "value2": 356
}]
```

A minha dúvida é como distribuir as informações do banco para gerar o JSON.
Para ter o resultado mais ou menos da forma abaixo:

[image: resultado]

Comment: `$json = json_encode($myObject);` ? A sua pergunta não está muito clara. Você tem que manipular o valor das chaves também?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira, a ideia seria colocar no category por exemplo 201601, e nos values, os vendedores que venderam, com o valor de cada um. Porque pelo que vi, cada "value" seria uma coluna no grafico